# Get new refresh token in oauth2.0 authorization code grant flow

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, amazon-cognito

I set up an authorization code grant flow for Google using Amazon Cognito. I'm able to get authorization code by calling `/login` endpoint and exchange it for `access_token`, `refresh_token` and `id_token` using the `/token` endpoint so I assume that it's set up more or less properly.

Unfortunately, when I try to exchange a `refresh_token` for new tokens using `/token` endpoint as well, I receive only `access_token` and `id_token` without new `refresh_token`. I've been trying to understand why it happens but [Amazon's documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) only briefly mentions that `refresh_token` is returned **only** for authorization code. What's more interesting, [auth0 documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-tokens/get-refresh-tokens) says that the `/token` endpoint should behave in a very different way - it shouldn't return new tokens directly but a new authorization code instead.

And now I'm pretty confused about what happens there. Is it Amazon who changed the flow of authorizing a user using authorization code? Or, more likely, I don't understand it and did something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refresh_token is generated at once time code authorization, we can reuse it to generate new access_token and id_token. On my approach, I am calling [initiateAuth](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property) method to generate new access_token and id_token :

```
  refreshToken() {
    let params = {
      AuthFlow: "REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH",
      ClientId: this.clientId,
      AuthParameters: {
        "REFRESH_TOKEN": [refresh_token_property],
        "DEVICE_KEY": null
      }
    };
    return this.cognitoIdp.initiateAuth(params).promise().then(data => {
      console.log(data.AuthenticationResult);
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e)
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi. I'm wondering now if it's possible to get a new refresh_token without asking the user to go through the google auth consent screen again? Or maybe once we exchanged the refresh_token we cannot get a new one without authorizing again?

Comment: Well, I would say like these:
- An Authorization Code can be used once only. Reuse the existing code will return the error invalid_grant, see this error responses https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html

- A refresh_token is reusable, we will need it to generate new both tokens (access & id)

- To get new refresh_token we need to relogin to generate authorization code & reauthorization the code to generate the new tokens (refresh, access, id) finally

Comment: Ok, that's what I was afraid about. Thanks!